# How to stub an external crate (or ways around it) in rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm trying to test a struct I have that looks something like this

```rust
struct CANProxy {
  socket: CANSocket
  // other stuff .......
}
impl CANProxy {
  pub fn new(can_device: &str) -> Self {
    let socket = CANSocket::open(can_device).unwrap();
    // other stuff .......
    
    Self { socket }
  }
}
```

What I want to test is that the proper messages are being sent across the socket, but I don't want to actually initialize a new can device while running my tests. I wanted to make a dummy CANSocket (which is from the cansocket crate) that uses the same functions and whatnot.

I tried creating a trait and extending the `socketcan::CANSocket` but it is super tedious and very redundant. I've looked at the `mockall` crate but I'm not sure if this would help in this situation. Is there an elegant way to accomplish what I want?

```rust
trait CANInterface {
  fn open(name: &str) -> Result<Self, SomeError>;
  // ... all the functions that are a part of the socketcan::CANSocket
  // which is a lot of repetition
}

///////////// Proxy code
struct<T: CANInterface> CANProxy<T> {
  socket: T
  // other stuff .......
}
impl<T: CANInterface> CANProxy<T> {
  pub fn open(can_device: &str) -> Result<Self, SomeError> {
    let socket = T::open(can_device).unwrap();
    // other stuff .......
    
    Ok(Self { socket })
  }
}

////////////// Stubbed CANInterfaces
struct FakeCANSocket;
impl CANInterface for FakeCANSocket {
  // ..... implementing the trait here
}
// extension trait over here
impl CANInterface for socketcan::CANSocket {
  // this is a lot of repetition and is kind of silly
  // because I'm just calling the same things
  fn open(can_device: &str) -> Self {
    CANSocket::open(can_device)
  }
  /// ..............
  /// ..............
  /// ..............
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all, there are indeed mock-targeted helper tools and crates such as [`::mockall`](https://docs.rs/mockall) to help with these patterns, *but only when you already have a trait-based API*. If you don't, that part can be quite tedious.

For what is worth, know that there are also other helper crates to help write that boiler-plate-y and redundantly-delegating trait impls such as your `open -> open` situation. One such example could be the [`::delegate`](https://lib.rs/crates/delegate) crate.

---

#### Mocking it with a test-target Cargo feature

With all that being said, my personal take for your very specific situation —the objective is to override a genuine impl with a mock one, **but just for testing purposes**—, would be to forgo the structured but heavyweight approach of generics & traits, and to instead embrace "duck-typed" APIs, *much like it is often done when having implementations on different platforms*. In other words, the following suggestion, conceptually, could be interpreted as your test environment being one such special "platform".

You'd then `#[cfg(…)]`-feature-gate the usage of the real impl, that is, the `CANSocket` type, in one case, and `#[cfg(not(…))]`-feature gate a mock definition of your own `CANSocket` type, provided you managed to copy / mock all of the genuine's type API that you may, yourself, be using.

1. Add a `mock-socket` Cargo feature to your project:

   ```ini
   [features]
   mock-socket = []
   ```

   - Remark: some of you may be thinking of using `cfg(test)` rather than `cfg(feature = "…")`, but that approach only works for *unit* (`src/…` files with `#[cfg(test)] mod tests`, `cargo test --lib` invocation) tests, it doesn't for integration tests (`tests/….rs` files, `cargo test --tests` invocation) or doctests (`cargo test --doc` invocation), since the library itself is then compiled *without* `cfg(test)`.
2. Then you can feature-gate Rust code using it

   ```rust
   #[cfg(not(feature = "mock-socket"))]
   use …path::to::genuine::CANSocket;

   #[cfg(feature("mock-socket"))]
   use my_own_mock_socket::CANSocket;
   ```
3. So that you can then define that `my_own_mock_socket` module (*e.g.*, in a `my_own_mock_socket.rs` file using `mod my_own_mock_socket;` declaration), provided you don't forget to feature-gate it itself, so that the compiler doesn't waste time and effort compiling it when not using the mocked `CANSocket` (which would yield `dead_code` warnings and so on):

   ```rust
   #[cfg(feature = "mock-socket")]
   mod my_own_mock_socket {
       //! It is important that you mimic the names and APIs of the genuine type!
       pub struct CANSocket…

       impl CANSocket { // <- no traits!
           pub fn open(can_device: &str) -> Result<Self, SomeError> {
               /* your mock logic */
           }

           …
       }
   }
   ```
4. That way, you can use:

   - either `cargo test`
   - or `cargo test --features mock-socket`

   to pick the implementation of your choice when running your tests
5. (Optional) if you know you will never want to run the tests for the real implementation, and only the mock one, then you may want to have that feature be enabled by default when running tests. While there is no direct way to achieve this, there is a creative way to work around it, by explicitly telling so to the self-as-a-lib dev-dependency that test code has (this dependency is always present implicitly, for what is worth). By making it explicit, we can then use the classic `features` `.toml` attribute to enable features for that `dev-dependency`:

   ```ini
   [dev-dependencies]
   your_crate_name.path = "."  # <- this is always implicitly present
   your_crate_name.features = ["mock-socket"]  # <- we add this
   ```

---

##### Bonus: not having to define an extra module for the mock code.

When the mock impls in question are short enough, it could be more tempting to just inline its definition and `impl` blocks. The issue then is that for every item so defined, it has to carry that `#[cfg…]` attribute which is annoying. That's when helper macros such as that of https://docs.rs/cfg-if can be useful, albeit adding a dependency for such a simple macro may seem a bit overkill (and, **very personally**, I find `cfg_if!`'s syntax too sigil heavy).

You can, instead, reimplement it yourself in less than a dozen lines of code:

```rust
macro_rules! cfg_match {
    ( _ => { $($tt:tt)* } $(,)? ) => ( $($tt)* );
    ( $cfg:meta => $expansion:tt $(, $($($rest:tt)+)?)? ) => (
        #[cfg($cfg)]
        cfg_match! { _ => $expansion }
        $($(
            #[cfg(not($cfg))]
            cfg_match! { $($rest)+ }
        )?)?
    );
} use cfg_match;
```

With it, you can rewrite steps `2.` and `3.` above as:

```rust
cfg_match! {
    feature = "mock-socket" => {
        /// Mock implementation
        struct CANSocket …

        impl CANSocket { // <- no traits!
            pub fn open(can_device: &str) -> Result<Self, SomeError> {
                /* your mock logic */
            }
            …
        }   
    },
    _ => {
        use …path::to::genuine::CANSocket;
    },
}
```

Comment: Such a well-written answer! This one goes into my library right away.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid a lot of the boilerplate by using a macro to create the wrapper trait and implement it for the base struct. Simplified example:

```
macro_rules! make_wrapper {
    ($s:ty : $t:ident { $(fn $f:ident ($($p:ident $(: $pt:ty)?),*) -> $r:ty;)* }) => {
        trait $t {
            $(fn $f ($($p $(: $pt)?),*) -> $r;)*
        }
        impl $t for $s {
            $(fn $f ($($p $(: $pt)?),*) -> $r { <$s>::$f ($($p),*) })*
        }
    }
}

struct TestStruct {}

impl TestStruct {
    fn foo (self) {}
}

make_wrapper!{
    TestStruct: TestTrait {
        fn foo (self) -> ();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=dc87c4d3028bfdb64449c4c0671b6281)

This will need to be extended to handle references (at least `&self` arguments), but you get the idea. You can refer to [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros.html) for more information on writing the macro.

Then you can use a crate like [`mockall`](https://crates.io/crates/mockall) to create your mock implementation of `TestTrait` or roll your own.